# Excel VBA to dynamically filter data

Tags: excel, vba

[Screenshot of SourceReport Excel that need to be filtered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS0vV.png)I need to develop a Excel VBA code to filter data on a worksheet, based on the filter conditions provided on the same worksheet.

Below is the code written for the same .. But this code filter the data from Row 1 instead of Row 4. Can you suggest an improvement?

```
Sub colFilter()

Dim ShtSource As Worksheet
Dim shtSrcHead As Range
Dim shtFilterData As Range
Dim filterStr As String

Set ShtSource = Sheets("SourceReport")
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim iCntr As Long

'get all of the filters of  sheet , assuming in row 2
lastCol = ShtSource.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set shtSrcHead = ShtSource.Range("A2", ShtSource.Cells(1, lastCol))
Set shtFilterData = ShtSource.Range("A4", ShtSource.Cells(1, lastCol))

j = 0

'actually loop through and find values
For Each srcHead In shtSrcHead
j = j + 1
If j = lastCol Then
j = 0
End If

If srcHead.Value = "INCLUDE" Or srcHead.Value = "EXCLUDE" Then
  filterStr = srcHead.Offset(1, 0).Value
  If srcHead.Value = "INCLUDE" Then
  Debug.Print filterStr
    Debug.Print j

   shtFilterData.AutoFilter Field:=j, Criteria1:=filterStr
  End If

  If srcHead.Value = "EXCLUDE" Then
    Debug.Print filterStr
    Debug.Print j

   shtFilterData.AutoFilter Field:=j, Criteria1:="<>" & filterStr
  End If
End If
Next srcHead

MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per below screenshot use the following sub to filter for multiple condition.

```
Sub MyFilter()
    Dim include() As String
    Dim exclude As String
    Dim FiltRng As Range
    Dim RngArea, RngArea2 As Range
    
        'Set RngArea = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select range include criteria.", Type:=8)
        'Set RngArea2 = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select range exclude criteria.", Type:=8)

        'include = Split(RngArea, ",")
    
    include = Split(Range("C2"), ",")
    exclude = Range("B2")
    Set FiltRng = Sheet1.Range("B4:C11")
    FiltRng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=include, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    FiltRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>" & exclude

End Sub
```

***Data position Screenshot***
[image]

> Adjust code for your data ranges.

Comment: Great Thanks Harun.

Comment: Is it possible to make the code more versatile by looping through each cell in Row 1(filter), if exclude then exclude values in range with filter value provided in Row2 and repeat the same for each column in row 1. Thus process the worksheet to the end of the range.

Comment: If you found the code working then you should accept my answer.

Comment: That is possible. Can you please clarify more details.

Comment: Hi Harun,My excel will have all headers in row 1, May or may not contain INCLUDE/EXCLUDE in Row 2 and Values to filter in row 3. Data will start from row 4 on-wards. Can you please suggest a code that would filter the data and remove the hidden rows instead of hard coding the field to filter ( Field:=2 ).

Comment: Hi Harun,My excel will have all headers in row 1, May or may not contain INCLUDE/EXCLUDE in Row 2 and Values to filter in row 3. Data will start from row 4 on-wards. 


Based on the INCUDE/EXCLUDE options provided , How can the data be filtered and hidden rows be removed.
Without hard coding the field to filter ( Field:=2 ).

Comment: What do you mean by removed hidden rows? Do you want to delete them?

Comment: Yes, delete the hidden rows

Comment: Can you share a sample workbook so that I can work on that and get back to you. You can share here google drive or dropbox link of sample file.

Comment: @ harun24hr  i have shared the screenshot of workbook and my code here. Can you review and give your feedback..